# ASP.NET MVC: How to print a variable returned from a Controller to the View on page load?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to sum all the values in a column of my table in SQL Database and display it  on page load itself. What I did is:

```
public ActionResult Sumthem() {
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM (Final) FROM SomeTable", con);
    cmd.Connection.Open();    


    ViewBag.FinalSUM = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    return View("Records");   
}
```

I want to print it like this (in Records.cshtml view):

```
@{var sum = ViewBag.FinalSUM;}
<h2>The Total is: @sum</h2>
```

Where and how should I call the controller method? I tried `@Url.Action("Sumthem", "Records")` in the Razor, but the controller method was not getting called. How can I return and print the value of the sum as soon as the page loads?

Edit: I tried this after that, but there was a System.StackOverflow error

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Sumthem", "Records");
var sum = ViewBag.FinalSUM;}
<h2>The Total is: @sum</h2>
//Returned PartialView instead of View from the Controller.
```

Comment: Are you looking for `@Html.RenderAction()`?

Comment: I guess you need to call `@Html.RenderAction("Sumthem", "Records")` and probably return `PartialView("Records")` from your controller action(also it's better to mark it with `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute).

Comment: I tried it. Now the controller method is getting called but it is throwing an error: System.StackOverflowException at the line `cmd.Connection.Open()`

Comment: You should not call from `RenderAction` from your partial view: it leads to the infinite loop which causes your exception. `RenderAction` should be called from place where you actually want to display you partial view. Also I noticed that you don't close the connection and don't use `using` directive to close it for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

**Action**:

```
public ActionResult Sumthem() {
    string constr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM (Final) FROM SomeTable", con);
        cmd.Connection.Open();

        ViewBag.FinalSUM = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        return PartialView("Records", new YourModel())
    }   
}
```

**Partial View**(Records.chstml):

```
@model YourModel
@*You can use data from your model as well*@
<h2>The Total is: @ViewBag.FinalSUM</h2>
```

**Usage**(in any view where you actually need your total value to be displayed):

```
@Html.RenderAction("Sumthem", "Records")
```

Comment: I have another model in my View file. We can only add one model to one view file, right? How can I display both entities?

Comment: In this case why don't you pass the model from your action? In your question your simple return `View("Records")` without providing a model.

Comment: I tried this. How will the View know which model I am referring to if there are two models? I have one DataTable already passed as a model to it. Now I have to pass the string.